# разница list и array

Tags: массивы, list, memory, data-structures

1. Можно ли говорить об общих различиях между типами данных list и array независимо от языка программирования? В частности, по способу доступа к элементам?
2. В Python что является "истинным" списком -- list или tuple?
3. Какая из этих структур требует больше памяти и при каких условиях?

Comment: Нет, в некоторых местах эти слова используют взаимозаменяемо. "Истинного" списка не существует как понятия в принципе, но tuple неизменяем, поэтому в кандидаты не годится. Вряд ли вам кто-то даст ответ на этот вопрос, поэтому проще создать миллион элементов и посмотреть расход памяти, это не так сложно; я не думаю, что для вас это должно иметь разницу, пока вы реально не уперлись в память.

Comment: да, соглашусть, что многие языки путают эти понятия. Но все же, array - это обычно один непрерывный кусок памяти, а list - это часто связанный список. Исходя из этого, array обычно потребляет меньше памяти, так как списку нужно хранить указатель на следующий элемент.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Строго говоря, связный список и массив - это различные структуры данных, которые не привязаны к конкретному языку программирования.

**Массив**

Массив - это совокупность однотипных данных, расположенных непрерывно в памяти. Доступ к элементу осуществляется по индексу за `O(1)` - мы обращаемся непосредственно к нужному участку памяти.

**Связанный список**

Доступ к элементу в связном списке в среднем занимает `O(N)` путем перебора элементов в поисках нужного. Способы доступа к элементам отличаются по реализации и от языка программирования. Например, на Java в стандартном классе `LinkedList` в зависимости от ситуации проход элементов может начинаться как с начала, так и с конца списка. И поиск элемента может осуществляться как по индексу, так и по сравнению элементов.

Связный список требует больших расходов памяти при прочих равных условиях за счет хранения указателей на следующий/предыдущий элементы и особенностей внутренней реализации.

Что касается Python: согласно [документации](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity):

> Internally, a list is represented as an array; the largest costs come from growing beyond the current allocation size (because everything must move), or from inserting or deleting somewhere near the beginning (because everything after that must move).

Как видим, внутренне `list` представляет собой массив, для `tuple` - аналогично.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что:
1) "Доступ к элементу в массиве осуществляется по индексу за O(1)," -- фактически мы обращаемся напрямую к ячейке памяти по адресу, на который ссылается элемент массива?
2) "доступ к элементу в связном списке - в среднем занимает O(N) путем перебора элементов в поисках нужного" -- имеется в виду обращение к первому элементу списка и после этого перебор до указанного индекса?
На всякий случай: в python можно обратиться по индексу к элементу обоих объектов -- как list, так и tuple. Если вы в курсе, здесь также присутствует то же самое различие?

Comment: @srgg67, дополнил свой ответ

Answer (score 5):

Нельзя сказать что есть какая-то разница независимо от языка программирования, так как автор каждого языка может определить эти слова так, как хочет.

Тем не менее, как мне кажется, разница между коллекциями список (list), массив (array) и кортеж (tuple) заключается в следующих характеристиках:

- **Фиксированность размера** - если размер коллекции фиксирован, то нельзя добавить или удалить элементы динамическим образом:

  ```
  int[] x = new int[2];
  x[0] = 50;
  x[1] = 45;
  x[2] = 40; // скорее всего тут будет ошибка или неопределённое поведение
  ```

  А если размер не фиксирован, можно добавить элементы динамическим образом:

  ```
  List<int> x = new List<int>();
  x.add(50);
  x.add(45);
  x.add(40);
  ```
- [**Изменчивость данных**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82) - если коллекция изменяемая, то можно изменить данные после создания, а если неизменяемая, то нет.

Конкретная разница:

- Размер фиксирован, изменяемый: массив (array)
- Размер фиксирован, неизменяемый: кортеж (tuple)
- Размер не фиксирован, изменяемый: список (list)
- Размер не фиксирован, неизменяемый: неизменяемый список (immutable list)

По поводу памяти и скорости: это точно зависит от языка и конкретного структура. Например, сложность доступа к элементу по индексу в списке может быть O(1) (например C# `List`), O(log(n)) (например куча), или O(n) (например связный список).

Answer (score 0):

Said, an array (data structure) of type TUPLE is 1 object in memory (containing data, for example, lard in salami). The program runs faster when you need to find an object

And a LIST is a chain of objects (each of these objects will be 1 data object, for example, each sausage in a chain). The program runs faster when you need to change any object.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык