# Проверка эквивалентности содержимого коллекций List<T>

Tags: c#, list

Есть один массив `List<Object1> objects1;`.
Он заполнен элементами

Также есть другой массив `List<Object1> objects2;`.
Он также заполнен элементами

В программе нужно проверить, одинаковы ли элементы в обоих массивах.
Я делаю `objects1.Equals(objects2)`.

**Всегда** выдаёт ***false***

Я думаю, что, возможно, массив List сам по себе ссылочный тип, и тогда получается, что никогда элементы массивов не совпадут.

Прошу помощи у более опытных анонов: **как проверить, одинаковы ли элементы обоих массивов?**

Comment: Оффтоп, но после решения проблемы, загляните сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473095/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-list-%D0%B8-array

Comment: @A1essandro, я всё понимаю. Называю список массивом для упрощения вопроса

Comment: Нужно ли учитывать, что элементы во втором списке могут быть такими же, но идти в другом порядке? Может ли в списке быть несколько одинаковых элементов?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да, нужно. В списке не может быть несколько одинаковых значений

Comment: В таком случае отмеченный ответ вам не подходит, он сравнивает в тот числе порядок следования, например `Console.WriteLine(new[]{ 1, 2, 3 }.SequenceEqual(new[]{ 3, 2, 1 }));` выдаст `False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
 var eq = objects1.SequenceEqual(objects2);
```

Comment: Я, возможно, что-то не так делаю, но к моим массивам не применяется метод `SequenceEqual()`

Comment: Вам нужно прописать `using System.Linq;`. Тогда Вам будет доступен этот метод.

Comment: я протестил и SequenceEqual(),по-моему применяется только к стандартным типам (на List<int> работает), а на List<MyClass> уже нет

Comment: Возможно этот метод хорошо работает с перечислениями

Comment: Всё работает. Пришлось немного покопаться и взять часть кода из https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx
@tym32167, спасибо

Comment: @eriksongerson пожалуйста. Рад, что помогло :)

Answer (score 2):

С учетом того, что порядок следования элементов в коллекциях может отличаться и в коллекциях нет повторяющихся элементов, подойдет такой код:

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] array2 = { 3, 2, 1 };
bool eq = !array1.Except(array2).Any()
       && !array2.Except(array1).Any();
Console.WriteLine(eq);
```

т.е. мы выбираем все элементы из первой коллекции, которых нет во второй и наоборот и потом смотрим, что если в итоге нет ни одного элемента на выходе, то коллекции содержат только одинаковые элементы.

Или такой:

```
bool eq = array1.Count() == array2.Count()
       && array1.Intersect(array2).Count() == array1.Count();
```

Т.е. в коллекциях одинаковое количество элементов и в их пересечении столько же элементов, этот вариант будет работать быстрее когда в коллекциях разное количество элементов.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню, Equals сравнивает адрес хранения в памяти для не базовых типов

Чтобы она заработала для списков нужно ее переопределить,либо есть 2 вариант

написать функцию с циклом где сравниваются все элементы каждый с каждым и тд,но придется с этим повозиться тк 2 одинаковых списка могут содержать элементы в разном порядке,значит нужно их перед сравнением еще отсортировать